# how do I change what fields are available when hovering over the Account Name/ lookup field on another record (Case) in SFDC?

Tags: page-layout

Users would like different fields visible when hovering over the Account Name, which is a lookup field to the Account record, on a Case.
[image]

I tried editing the Account Compact layout but that didn't change what is showing. Where do I change what fields are shown? IE: I want to remove the Mobile and Account Owner and add the account Number and Shipping address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover detail is called **Mini Page Layout**.

More information from this article : [Use of hover detail settings to change the display field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325370&type=1)

To change fields displayed, go to the parent object page layout :

> Click Setup | Objects and Fields | Object Manager | Select Object | Page Layout

> Once the above click path is selected: 
> Select 'edit' for the page layout you wish to change the hover details for.
> At the top right of the page, in the blue bar just above the available fields, you will find the link labeled **Mini Page Layout**. 
> Click the **Mini Page Layout** link to load a new page with two columns.
> The left column denotes the available fields, and the right indicates fields included in the hover detail.
> Select a field from the left column and add it to the right column to add it to the hover detail and vice versa to remove it.
> Click save. 
> The new fields you selected or removed will be added or removed from the hover detail.

Comment: How do I know which page layout to edit? I need to edit the Account lookup fields displayed on a Case record page layout so I'm not sure which Account Page layout it would be using via the lookup hover on the Case page.

Comment: Every page layout assigned to a valid recordtype

Comment: So I would edit every Account Page Layouts mini page layout? Then I assume the details will be the same from any record they hover over the Account name from correct?

Comment: @user7417 yes, if you want the same fields to appear in all mini page layout, then yes you need to update all of them. if you want specific fields by mini page layout, then it depends on the page layout assignment by profile and/or if you have record type

Comment: So I did that and didn't see any change when hovering. I realized now that the Account lookup records that are related to Cases are actually Person Accounts so I need to update those page layouts instead! Thanks.

Comment: @user7417 Glad this worked for you. If you don't mind, please mark the answer as accepted :)